# Do mini-filter functions need APCs enabled?

Tags: driver, device-driver, kernel, wdk

Many Zw* functions that work with files (such as **ZwCreateFile**) need to be called at PASSIVE_LEVEL with APCs enabled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566424%28VS.85%29.aspx. This is because, internally, I/O operations are asynchronously and the completion of an operation is delivered through an APC (correct me if I'm wrong).

However, the documentation for similar functions from a mini-filter (such as **FltCreateFile**, **FltReadFile**, etc) does not specify that APCs should be enabled. Is it safe to call FltCreateFile/FltReadFile with APCs disabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `ZwCreateFile` and `FltCreateFile` only at PASSIVE_LEVEL and with special kernel APCs enabled (normal kernel APCs can be disabled).

Comment: "For example, any routine that relies on an I/O completion routine (such as IoVolumeDeviceToDosName) must be called with special kernel APCs enabled." - Windows Driver Kit: Kernel-Mode Driver Architecture, Disabling APCs.